# No such file or directory but library exists?

Tags: macos, makefile, static-libraries

I'm been working on this issue for some time now, and I hope someone can point out what I'm missing.

```
$ make clean && make libvpnpp.a
c++ -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -I. -I/usr/local/include/ -c VpnInit.cpp
libtool -static -o libvpnpp.a VpnInit.o
libvpnpp.a
make: libvpnpp.a: No such file or directory
make: *** [libvpnpp.a] Error 1
```

However, when I perform an `ls`, the library *is* there:

```
$ ls *.a
libvpnpp.a
```

And it *is* multiarch:

```
$ lipo -info libvpnpp.a 
Architectures in the fat file: libvpnpp.a are: x86_64 i386
```

Here are the makefile rules and recipes that are relevant:

```
IS_DARWIN = $(shell uname -s | $(EGREP) -i -c "Darwin")
ifeq ($(IS_DARWIN),1)
    CXXFLAGS += -arch x86_64 -arch i386
    AR = libtool
    ARFLAGS = -static -o
endif
...

libvpnpp.a: $(VPNPP_LIB_OBJS)
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $(VPNPP_LIB_OBJS)
    $(RANLIB) $@
...

%.o : %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -I$(VPNPP_INCL) -I$(CRYPTOPP_INCL) -c $<
```

Why does `make` fail with `No such file or directory` even though the library is created and exists?

---

Here's the tail from `make -d`:

```
...
c++ -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -I. -I/usr/local/include/ -c VpnInit.cpp
Putting child 0x7fe669c0ff10 (VpnInit.o) PID 59119 on the chain.
Live child 0x7fe669c0ff10 (VpnInit.o) PID 59119 
Reaping winning child 0x7fe669c0ff10 PID 59119 
Removing child 0x7fe669c0ff10 PID 59119 from chain.
    Successfully remade target file `VpnInit.o'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file `libvpnpp.a'.
  Must remake target `libvpnpp.a'.
libtool -static -o libvpnpp.a VpnInit.o
Putting child 0x7fe669c111d0 (libvpnpp.a) PID 59127 on the chain.
Live child 0x7fe669c111d0 (libvpnpp.a) PID 59127 
Reaping winning child 0x7fe669c111d0 PID 59127 
libvpnpp.a
make: libvpnpp.a: No such file or directory
Live child 0x7fe669c111d0 (libvpnpp.a) PID 59138 
Reaping losing child 0x7fe669c111d0 PID 59138 
make: *** [libvpnpp.a] Error 1
Removing child 0x7fe669c111d0 PID 59138 from chain.
$
```

Comment: use strace/ktrace (whatever variant exists on osx) and see what file make is trying to open but does not find. ALso you could use debug flags to get a more verbose output from make

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like `$(RANLIB)` is empty and then the line `$(RANLIB) $@` resolves to just `libvpnpp.a`. As the first word on a line, the shell wants to execute a program named `libvpnpp.a` which it doesn't find (probably because `.` is not in `PATH`).

Try setting `RANLIB=:` in the makefile or as a make variable. Or investigate why `RANLIB` isn't set properly.

Comment: Indeed. `RANLIB` is *not* an [implicit variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Variables) in make. Sigh...